# SSIS C# OpenXML to generate Excel File Failing

Tags: c#, ssis, openxml

I am using OpenXML to generate Excel file using C# in an SSIS package.

I did this because we do not have Excel installed on the Server so this should work without needing Excel installed.

This works locally, but is failing when moving to the PROD server.  It is failing on the script task and I am getting this error:

```
Executed as user: MI\SQLAgentAccount. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute     Package Utility  Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  10:46:49 AM  Error: 2015-10-15 10:46:50.49     Code: 0x00000001     Source: Save To Excel Without Excel      Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  10:46:49 AM  Finished: 10:46:50 AM  Elapsed:  0.827 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.
```

I am including in the references the OpenXML and WindowBase objects and adding them with the "using" statements.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
```

Do these need to be registered with the GAC?  Or is there a way to include them in the project (inside the script task within SSIS)?  There is the setting for "Copy To Local" inside the C# script task in SSIS, but not sure what/how this would work inside SSIS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the user that is running the SSIS package on the prod server? Are you using the Agent to run it? The agent's user must be granted read (and write if required) access onto the folder where the Excel file is

Comment: Its using the sa user, but yes we have othe rpackages that can create, edit, delete, update files on those folders.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to ensure you have it available from the GAC and also copy the assembly to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\

Just doing some research on this myself and found the following link that confirmed the issue and resolution:
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/81/posts/11263/referencing-an-assembly-inside-ssis-script-task.aspx

Comment: One further reference that might help here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/3180/

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but is there anyway to include the .dll in the SSIS C# script task itself without adding it to the GAC?  

I dont have access to add that to the server.

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't appear so.  The only alternatives, which I suspect will not be palatable, would be to move the OpenXml processing to somewhere outside the script but still accessible by SSIS, e.g. using an execute process task to run a program, which could have a reference to the library where the c# script could not.

Comment: Yea that wont work either, cause I cant add/install anything on the server which I would have to do for that solution as well.

I need to get it to work without installing anything on the server at all, must use all standard code that is on the server already.